# Is 'IEnumerator' called on every frame with 'yield WaitForSeconds'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is an example of two functions below. One is using `Update` and one using `IEnumerator`. I know that the `Update` function is called every frame. ***My question:*** is `IEnumerator` also called every frame?

Note: I am using `yield WaitForSeconds` and not `yield WaitForEndOfFrame` or `yield null`.

**Update function (example 1):**

```
//_ratePerSecond is how often the functions must execute
void Update()
{
    if ((CurrentPoints >= MinPoints) && Time.time >= _timeToChangeValue)
    {
        _timeToChangeValue = Time.time + _ratePerSecond;
        CurrentPoints += 1
    }
}
```

**IEnumerator function (example 2):**

```
//this is called with StartCoroutine(ChangeValue());
IEnumerator ChangeValue()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_ratePerSecond);

        if (CurrentPoints >= MinPoints)
        {
            CurrentPoints += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Below is a performance test done with 10000 objects running functions in example 1 & 2. Highlighted in red is `Update` function (example 1), highlighted in green is `IEnumerator` function (example 2).

*Using random delay of 0-1 seconds:*
[image]

*Using random delay of 1-2 seconds:*
[image]

*Conclusion from performance test*: The `Update` function is less efficient. `IEnumerator` performs even better when the delays are bigger.

Comment: You run `ChangeValue` by using `StartCourtine`, and then the function waits a couple of seconds, so where would it call it every frame?

Comment: I'm not sure if the engine calls the Enumerators on every frame. So what I'm asking is: does the unity engine pause the execution of the IEnumerator and say 'I am done for this frame' and then pick up where it left off on the next frame (with all the state information if had from the previous frame)

Comment: Just a cautionary note, running an isolated test such as this is *not* going to give you an accurate benchmark that would be applicable to real-world scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IEnumerator also called every frame?

With the coroutine function in your question, the answer is **No**.

The [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) function will **suspend** the `ChangeValue()` function until is has finished waiting for the specified (`_ratePerSecond`) seconds then it will execute the code in the `while` loop, jump back to the beginning of the `while` loop again and suspend itself for (`_ratePerSecond`) seconds again. This will repeat until stopped with `StopCoroutine`/`StopAllCoroutines` or `yield break` is called in the `while` loop.

Below is a coroutine version of the code in your `Update` function.

```
IEnumerator ChangeValue()
{
    while (true)
    {    
        if ((CurrentPoints >= MinPoints) && Time.time >= _timeToChangeValue)
        {
            _timeToChangeValue = Time.time + _ratePerSecond;
            CurrentPoints += 1;
        }

        //Wait for a frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you have to call this function with `StartCoroutine(ChangeValue());` not `ChangeValue();`

Comment: So is the `IEnumerator` more efficient to use? taking into consideration the context switching (stopping/starting of the 'thread') vs the `Update`  function which executes on every frame

Comment: You use `IEnumerator` if you need to something things in sequence. For example, move from A to B. Wait for 3 seconds. Move from B to A. And yes, it should absolutely be used for stopping/starting of any operation since you won't have to do that in the `Update` function which will run for every frame.